# Priority Pass Select in Europe?

Tags: payment-cards, prioritypass

In the US, some credit cards (like the [Chase Sapphire Reserve](https://www.chase.com/card-benefits/sapphirereserve/travel) or [Amex Platinum](https://global.americanexpress.com/card-benefits/detail/the-lounge-collection/platinum)) include a [Priority Pass Select](https://www.prioritypass.com/select), which gives free access to Priority Pass lounges **and** allows bringing a guest. These passes are not sold by Priority Pass directly.

I live and work in Switzerland, so I have no credit history in the US, and European credit cards typically offer much fewer benefits than American cards.

Is there any way to obtain a Priority Pass Select or similar lounge benefits as a European citizen, through any sort of financial institution, either in the US or Europe, without a US credit history? Ideally for a price comparable to buying the Priority Pass directly (399 EUR).

Comment: You could consider buying Priority Pass via affiliate link for cheaper, for example https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/credit-cards/cheap-airport-lounge-access/ £305/year (~331 EUR) Scroll down to "Frequent airport lounge user? Consider annual membership" section.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, American Express in Switzerland includes a Priority Pass in their [Platinum card](https://www.americanexpress.ch/en/credit-cards/platinum-credit-card/). The annual fee is 850 CHF per year, but there's an offer of 50% off for the first year that makes it 425 CHF, which is slightly less than buying a Priority Pass directly (399 EUR, which is ~435 CHF as of writing this post).

Might be worth getting this card for the first year only, although I don't know if it's trivial to be approved for the card.

Comment: Some banks in Switzerland offer Priority Passes as part of their Credit Card offerings, with either entries for free or (for cheaper cards) with a €22 fee per entry. Might be cheaper, depending on how often you use it.